# Failed to acquire token with authorization code using Microsoft graph API with Java Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I have followed the guide in microsoft docs and successfully acquire the authorization code when I directly put the URL in the browser. But if I start the Spring application and do the same action, it will say: [invalid_request]. So I have done the following: I get the authorization code before start the Spring application and then run the Spring application with the following code:

```
final AuthorizationCodeCredential authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId("1234")
            .clientSecret("4567") //required for web apps, do not set for native apps
            .authorizationCode("abcd12345")
            .redirectUrl("http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure")
            .build();

//        List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read".split(","));
        List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default".split(","));

    final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, authCodeCredential);

    final GraphServiceClient graphClient =
            GraphServiceClient
                    .builder()
                    .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                    .buildClient();


    Message message = new Message();
    message.subject = "Meet for lunch?";
    ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
    body.contentType = BodyType.TEXT;
    body.content = "The new cafeteria is open.";
    message.body = body;
    LinkedList<Recipient> toRecipientsList = new LinkedList<Recipient>();
    Recipient toRecipients = new Recipient();
    EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
    emailAddress.address = "opoiuiotqq@gmail.com";
    toRecipients.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    toRecipientsList.add(toRecipients);
    message.toRecipients = toRecipientsList;

    boolean saveToSentItems = false;

    graphClient.me()
            .sendMail(UserSendMailParameterSet
                    .newBuilder()
                    .withMessage(message)
                    .withSaveToSentItems(saveToSentItems)
                    .build())
            .buildRequest()
            .post();
```

It just pops an error message: ERROR com.azure.identity.AuthorizationCodeCredential - Azure Identity => ERROR in getToken() call for scopes [https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: Failed to acquire token with authorization code.

So I think is it related to the problem that I mentioned at the begining. Here is the guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code

Comment: You may try to follow [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-spring-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/sign-in)

Comment: After studying its code, it works for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer your question exactly, but as mentioned in the DOCs you can Redeem a code for an access token with the two ways mentioned in the DOC, that is the

1)Request an access token with a client_secret-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-client_secret

2)Request an access token with a certificate credential-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-certificate-credential
can you try this , hope this helps.